# How to pass data from an Activity to Tab Fragments using ViewPager?

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

Hey StackOverFlow community ! I really need help.. :(

I'm searching for 2 or 3 hours now and didn't find anything that is relevant and simple.

**I explain the context :** 
I have an Activity A1. This activity contains 3 fragments F1, F2, F3. It uses a ViewPager so the 3 fragments are in facts selected either by selecting a tab or by swiping the screen and this works.

**What I want to do now :** 
For some reasons, I call a Web Service for data in the activity. The data is dependent on the intent that the activity A1 gets from the original calling activity A0 (It's a group_id). So, I want to send this data that I get in A1 from the Web Service to each of my fragments F1, F2 and F3.

Do you have a solution or an explanation of how the to pass data to fragments in ViewPager ?

Thanks a lot!

**There is the base code of my Activity A1 :**

> ```
> public class ShowGroupActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
>         ActionBar.TabListener {
>
> private ViewPager viewPager;
>     private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
>     private ActionBar actionBar;
>     // Tab titles
>     private String[] tabs = { "Infos", "Parcours", "Mur" };
> @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_group);
>
>         // Initilization
>         viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
>         actionBar = getActionBar();
>         mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
>
>         viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
>         actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
>         actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
>
>         // Adding Tabs
>         for (String tab_name : tabs) {
>             actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
>                     .setTabListener(this));
>         }
>
>         viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
>
>             @Override
>             public void onPageSelected(int position) {
>                 // on changing the page
>                 // make respected tab selected
>                 actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
>             }
>         });
>
>  @Override
>     public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
>         // on tab selected
>         // show respected fragment view
>         viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
>     }
> ```

**Here is an example of a fragment : F1 (In which I want to display some data given by A1).**

> ```
> public class GroupInfoFragment extends Fragment {
>
> public GroupInfoFragment() {
>         // Required empty public constructor
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>                              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
>         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_group_info, container, false);
>
>         return v;
>
>     }
>
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and fastest way to do it is by using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).
Just *post* an event at your *onResponse* method in the activity and the fragment will handle the rest.

**Activity-**

- Create a *NetworkResponceEvent* class
- OnResponse called: post a new *NetworkResponceEvent* to the eventbus.

**Fragment**-

- Register- onResume
- UnRegister- osPause
- Create method onEvent(NetworkResponceEvent e)- handle all of the
  updates here.

Comment: But there is a problem here!
The event is not called in fragment that is not visible(selected tab) , so data is not received by other fragments

Comment: If the fragment is a different tab then it will get called. When u switch tab, onpause of the fragment didn't get called.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `getActivity()` method from your fragments.

I would recommend declaring an interface inside your fragment, like this:

```
public class GroupInfoFragment extends Fragment {
...
public interface Callbacks {
    // you should declare methods for returning the data you want form your activity here
    Foo getData();
}
...
}
```

And then implementing this interface in your `ShowGroupActivity` class, like this:

```
public class ShowGroupActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener, GroupInfoFragment.Callbacks {
...
    @Override
    Foo getData() {
        return mData;
    }
...
}
```

Then you would be able to get the data you want from your fragment classes by calling:

```
GroupInfoFragment.Callbacks callbacks = (GroupInfoFragment.Callbacks) getActivity();
Foo data = callbacks.getData;
```

By doing this, you can implement your fragment class without worrying about the activity implementation.

---

**Additional Notes**

You can also override your fragment's `onAttach()` method so you can always guarantee that your fragment is being attached to an activity that implements the `Callback` interface. You can also keep a reference to the `Callback` instance:

```
Callbacks mCallbacks;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
    }

    mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
}
```